# Wondering about where I can find some literature about what my professor called “Generalized geometric series”

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So geometric series are nice and easy all around. But in my last text my analysis teacher brought some problems up, such as the following:

- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{ln(n)}}$
- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{ln(n)}}$

After the test we talked about the convergence of the general case when you have a series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{f(n)}$. where $r$ is a real number and $f(n)$ is a function such that is increasing on the positives. Is this an actual topic? Is there a general way to find the values of $r$ such that it converges? Thanks in advance for any help that you might provide.

Comment: These are more like a p-series than a geometric series, notice $\frac{1}{k^{\ln n}} = \frac{1}{e^{\ln(k) \ln (n)}} = \frac{1}{n^{\ln k}}$.

Comment: In the particular case when $f(x)$ is logarithmic, then yes. But I'm mainly wondering about the general case where $f$ can be any increasing function. Although, i'll definitely have a peak at some of my other analysis books to see if they explore something similar. Thank you!